# Creating moodle plugin to accept REST calls and create activities/notice/files

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

Im quite new to moodle development. Im trying to post activity/notice to a selected course. I could not find any webservice for creating activities within a course. Is there any way i could create a plug-in where i could make a REST call to the plug so that it would create a notice?. An example would help allot.

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1**

To create local plugin you can follow following folder structure according to Moodle documentation (https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins)-

> local/
>
> > yourplugin/
> >
> > > db/
> > >
> > > > access.php
> > > >
> > > > install.php
> > > >
> > > > install.xml
> > >
> > > lang/
> > >
> > > > en/
> > > >
> > > > > yourplugin.php
> > >
> > > index.php
> > >
> > > settings.php
> > >
> > > version.php

Meanwhile, creating local plugin does not always really solve all problems as there are limitation depending what you really want to achieve.

what worked for me was editing //moodle_dir/course/modedit.php file, and i was able to make REST Call to add scorm activity to any course i want.